# git-subtree branch switching & directory layout

Tags: git

So I'm kinda new to git -- or at least git on the console, have been using Tortoise git. And I find myself in something I would consider a relatively "common" use-case:

I have several repositories planned: generic/shared code repo_sN, application code repo_appN.

The folder structure for some shared repository should look something like this:

```
repo_s0
+---folder_s0_0
|       file.txt
|       
\---folder_s0_1
        file.txt
```

The folder structure for an application repository might use multiple shared repositories:

```
repo_app0
+---folder_s0_0
|       file.txt
|       
+---folder_s0_1
|       file.txt
|       
+---folder_s1_0
|       file.txt
|       
\---folder_s1_1
        file.txt
```

Now, I want the above repo_app0 folder structure committed to remote_repo_app0, i.e. including all shared subdirs with content.
I also want to be able to push changes I make in any of the folder_sN_N back to their proper repositories repo_sN/pull updates from said repositories.

However, two problems arose. Using git-subtree, I am only able to get things working like so:

```
git subtree add --prefix=s0 remote_repo_s0 master
```

This gives me

```
repo_app0
+---s0
|   +---folder_s0_0
|   |       file.txt
|   |       
|   \---folder_s0_1
|           file.txt
|           
\---s1
    +---folder_s1_0
    |       file.txt
    |       
    \---folder_s1_1
            file.txt
```

Which is undesirable, because it doesn't *hide* the fact that sub-repositories are used anymore and clutters my source directory unnecessarily and violates my workplace's default folder structure.

I pushed back commits to repo_app0 using

```
git commit -m "My commit"
git push remote_repo_app0 master
git subtree push --prefix=s1 remote_repo_s1 master
```

However, this would push changes made in folders sN as well, which rules out a common top directory for all folder_sN_N as well :-/.

Secondly, for instance, I might need to switch branches of repo_s0 from "master" to "compatibility" for compiling app0 using older compilers. So the idea is that the functionality does not change, while the implementation does to conform to older language syntax.

I have been unable to to find out how to use a subtree like a "regular" git working directory and switch branches.

So is this possible at all? Is this a really esoteric use-case and all people just symlink/copy by hand/??? needed parts? More-so, is there a solution I'm missing here?

Comment: Why don't you simply use submodules?

Comment: Hi, I just rechecked the submodules documentation.
As far as I can see, I would have the same disadvantages as above plus not being able to commit the shared code directly to my application repository plus not being able to commit and push stuff to the shared code repository. So it seems even more complicated than subtrees at the moment.